# What does "(_:_:_)" mean in Haskell (non-exhaustive pattern matching error from GHCI)?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm getting the following error from GHCI when I run my Haskell program:

```
"Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
 In an equation for `recaList': Patterns not matched: (_:_:_)"
```

I've been searching the web/SO, but can't seem to find an explanation for what `(_:_:_)` is. My guess would be just an empty list, but I've accounted for that in my function.

Not sure if it's relevant, but here's my program:

```
recaList :: [Int] -> [Int]
recaList [] = []
recaList [x] = map recaMan [x]
```

I think the issue is just that I have no idea what `(_:_:_)` is.

Comment: You could've googled "Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive". Gives many relevant results. :) About "`_`": used in plain text, it is interpreted as an _italics_ marker on SO (as is `*`). To write *code* we escape it by enclosing it in backticks ` like so: `_italics_ marker` (I typed ``"`_italics_ marker`"``. To show code containing backticks we enclose it in double backticks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
recaList :: [Int] -> [Int]
recaList [] = []
recaList [x] = map recaMan [x]
```

This is matching empty lists and lists containing one element. You have failed to match any list containing two or more elements. I believe what you meant was

```
recaList :: [Int] -> [Int]
recaList [] = []
recaList xs = map recaMan xs
```

No need for the brackets. However, `map` will return the empty list if given it as input, so your first case is also unnecessary. Although the above snippet will work, this would be more idiomatic.

```
recaList :: [Int] -> [Int]
recaList xs = map recaMan xs
```

As to your question about what the error syntax means, `:` is the list construction operator, so `(x:xs)` matches any nonempty list, binding the first element to `x` and the rest to `xs`. `(x:y:ys)` does the same, but it binds the first to `x`, the second to `y`, and the remainder to `ys`. An underscore simply indicates an ignored value, so `(_:_:_)` matches any list of at least two elements. The compiler is telling you that you failed to match this case.